# RDLC with Non AlphaNumeric Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I have a simple subreport that appears to be behaving not so simply.  The report is sorted on the description field A-Z which works great as the field is always uppercase alpha numeric characters for the most part.  However, there is one item that can be generated into the database that has a description of say '_TOBACOO' which has an underscore as its starting character. This entry is appearing at the START of the report despite the sort order.

Surely the A-Z sort order of an RDLC report should behave correctly and put the entry at the end since _ appears after all alpha characters in any given character set I've seen.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up using a grouping level to ensure that it worked properly.  As the data was coming from .NET classes rather than SQL I couldn't do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Please try your query in this manner:

```
select * from tablename order by cast(columnname as varbinary(500)).
```

And here is the explanation for the same: http://andrusdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/10/string-sort-vs-word-sort-in-net.html